# Is there an API call that can get me a user's access_token?

Tags: support, api

I'm trying to create a connector between Microsoft's Power Platform and the Stack API. Since the server ↔ server auth flow is happening outside of code I control, I can't grab the `access_token` from the OAuth hash. I'm reaching out to them as well to add functionality to do so, but that'll take time even if they accept the request.

Facebook (whom this API was modeled after) has the ability to make an API call to get a valid `access_token`, but I haven't found one here (unless I had an access token to start with).